# Type guard which narrows generic type T to Pick<T, U>

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type guard, which sole purpose is to check the existence of property in object and that it has some value in it.

With type system I want to say this phrase to compiler, if type guard check succeeds:

> This is an input object, if type guard succeeds then output is an *object*
>   with **lineHeight** property

For exact object it looks like this:

```js
type PickedLineHeight = Pick<TextStyle, "lineHeight">
type NonNullableLineHeight = Required<PickedLineHeight>

function hasLineHeight(style: object): style is NonNullableLineHeight {
    return (
        style.hasOwnProperty("lineHeight") &&
        (style as PickedLineHeight).lineHeight !== undefined
    )
}
```

How would I develop more generic version of function like **hasProperty(style, prop)**?

My attempt was:

```js
function hasProperty<T extends { [key: string]: any}, U extends keyof T>(style: T, prop: U): style is Pick<T, U> {
    return (
        style.hasOwnProperty(prop) &&
        style[prop] !== undefined
    )
}
```

but I constantly get this error message, which I can't eliminate or understand

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably type `hasProperty()` this way:

```
function hasProperty<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
    style: T,
    prop: K
): style is T & { [P in K]-?: Exclude<T[K], undefined> } {
    return style.hasOwnProperty(prop) && style[prop] !== undefined;
}
```

This should reflect that `hasProperty()` will verify that the property exists and is not `undefined`. The guarded type, `T & { [P in K]-?: Exclude<T[K], undefined> }` is assignable to `T` (which is what the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) `T & ...` says) and has extra restrictions on the `K`-keyed property.  Note that `{ [P in K]-?: Exclude<T[K], undefined> }` could also be written `Required<Record<K, Exclude<T[K], undefined>>`, which might be more understandable.  Let's make sure it behaves as expected:

```
interface Example {
    required: string;
    optional?: string;
    requiredButPossiblyUndefined: string | undefined;
    requiredButPossiblyNull: string | null;
}

function checkExample(ex: Example) {
    ex.required.toUpperCase(); // okay

    // hasProperty de-optionalizes optional properties
    ex.optional.toUpperCase(); // error, possibly undefined
    if (hasProperty(ex, "optional")) {
        ex.optional.toUpperCase(); // okay
    }

    // hasProperty removes undefined from list of possible values
    ex.requiredButPossiblyUndefined.toUpperCase(); // error, possibly undefined
    if (hasProperty(ex, "requiredButPossiblyUndefined")) {
        ex.requiredButPossiblyUndefined.toUpperCase(); // okay
    }

    // hasProperty doesn't do anything with null
    ex.requiredButPossiblyNull.toUpperCase(); // error, possibly null
    if (hasProperty(ex, "requiredButPossiblyNull")) {
        ex.requiredButPossiblyNull.toUpperCase(); // error, possibly null
    }
}
```

Looks good.  Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwIYGcAKAnOAHAU2ygE8AeAFUQIA8oCwATdROAIwCsDoAaRAaWp0GzRAGsCJOMEQUAfAAoAsAChE6xOlIAbAgC5ZPVRsR5ceA-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)

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Accidentaly I came up to this soluton, which is for my opinion, is the same as which shows error.

But anyway, this is working without complains:

```js
function hasProperty<T extends object>(style: T, prop: keyof T): style is Pick<T, typeof prop> {
    return (
        style.hasOwnProperty(prop) &&
        style[prop] !== undefined
    )
}

function hasFontSize(style: TextStyle) {
    return hasProperty(style, "fontSize")
}

function hasLineHeight(style: TextStyle) {
    return hasProperty(style, "lineHeight")
}
```

Comment: These types say that property on object exists. But Typescript still assumes value under that property can be `undefined`.